# ShadCn UI ResizablePanelGroup expand in the available space without specifying a custom height

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, shadcnui

I am stuck in a middle of CSS issue with `ResizablePanelGroup` component. In my page layout I am trying to place a header and a `ResizablePanelGroup` with 4 panels. Page should have a100vh and within that I want to place other components. After placing Header my `ResizablePanelGroup` should expand the rest of the height available in the space without manually specifying a height. Only the Content I am putting in the `ResizablePanel`  should be scrollable when they exceed the space available in the panel.

[image]

Above is the current status of the layout and red are should expand the rest of the height available.

```
import ChatNav from "@/components/chat/ChatNav";
import Header from "@/components/common/Header";
import { Toggle } from "@/components/ui/toggle";
import UtilContext from "@/context/UtilContext";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { useContext, createContext } from "react";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-black">
      <div className="absolute  inset-4">
        <UtilContext>
          <Header />

          <div className="bg-red-500"> {children}</div>
        </UtilContext>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
"use client";
import Chat from "@/components/chat/Chat";
import {
  ResizableHandle,
  ResizablePanel,
  ResizablePanelGroup,
} from "@/components/ui/resizable";
import ChatNav from "@/components/chat/ChatNav";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UtilPanelContext } from "@/context/UtilContext";
import LSide from "@/components/chat/LSide";

const page = () => {
  const { leftPanel } = useContext(UtilPanelContext);

  return (
    <div className="h-full">
      {/* sidbar */}
      <ResizablePanelGroup direction="horizontal">
        {/* side nav */}
        <ResizablePanel defaultSize={10} className="min-w-[80px] max-w-[80px]">
          <div className="h-full flex flex-col">
            <div className="flex-grow-1"> Nav</div>
          </div>
          {/* <ChatNav /> */}
        </ResizablePanel>
        <ResizableHandle />

        {/* history panel */}
        <ResizablePanel defaultSize={leftPanel ? 30 : 0}>
          <div>LSide</div>
          {/* <LSide /> */}
        </ResizablePanel>
        <ResizableHandle withHandle />

        {/* chat workspace */}
        <ResizablePanel defaultSize={50}>
          <div>Chat</div>
          {/* <Chat /> */}
        </ResizablePanel>
        <ResizableHandle withHandle />

        {/* side panel */}
        <ResizablePanel defaultSize={50}>
          <h1>Hellow </h1>
        </ResizablePanel>
      </ResizablePanelGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

[image]

Kind of the expectation I want. `ResizablePanelGroup` expands in the green color space and inner panels have scrollable views when the available space exceeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we should fill the free vertical space with `ResizablePanelGroup`. We can do this with a vertical flex layout in `RootLayout` (assuming `UtilContext` does not render any HTML):

```html
<div className="absolute  inset-4 flex flex-col">
  <UtilContext>
    <Header />
    
    <div className="bg-red-500 min-h-0 grow"> {children}</div>
```

[image: Full height fill]

Then, to make each `ResizablePanel` vertically scrollable, apply `overflow-y: auto !important` or `overflow-y: scroll !important` to them via `!overflow-y-auto` or `!overflow-y-scroll` respectively. `auto` means a scrollbar only appears when needed, whereas `scroll` means a scrollbar will always be present. We need the `!important` flag to override the inline `overflow: hidden` style that are added to the HTML elements.

```html
<ResizablePanel defaultSize={50} className="!overflow-y-auto">
```

See this working in [this StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so77849991?file=src%2FRootLayout.jsx,src%2Fpage.jsx).